# Can we pass parameters to a generator when we iterate it via for..of?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-generator

I am thinking about a scenario of building up a promise queue:

```
//Let's assume that promises is an array of promises
var promiseQueue = [];
for (var promise of promises) {
    if (promiseQueue.length) promiseQueue[promiseQueue.length - 1].then(promise);
    promiseQueue.push(promise);
}
```

I am thinking about implementing a `function` called `resolver`:

```
function *resolve() {
    var promise;
    while (promise = yield) Promise.resolve(promise);
}
```

and then iterating it:

```
var promiseGenerator = resolve();
```

The problem is the for..of here which would be responsible for the actual iteration:

```
for (var r of promiseGenerator) {

}
```

At the code above the generator will be successfully iterated, but unfortunately I am not aware of a way to successfully pass a parameter to this generator at the iteration of for..of.

I would like to clarify that I do not need an alternative, I am perfectly aware that we can do something like this:

```
for (var p in promiseQueue) promiseGenerator.next(promiseQueue[p]);
```

I am specifically interested to know whether I can pass parameters to the generator when I execute a for..of cycle.

EDIT

The problem raised by amn is that in the example he/she was focusing on would always get `undefined`. That's true if we pass `undefined` to `next()`, but not true if we pass something else. The problem I was raising is that a for..of loop does not allow us to pass anything to `yield`, which is this specific question is all about, the example is a mere illustration of the problem, showing that the promises we would create will never be created in a for..of loop. However, there is life for Iterable objects outside the realm of for..of loops and we can pass defined values into the `yield`. An example with the criticized code chunk can look like:

```
function *resolve() {
    var promise;
    while (promise = yield) Promise.resolve(promise);
}

var responses = [];
var f = resolve();
var temp;
for (var i = 10; !(temp = f.next(i)).done; i--) responses.push(temp);
```

As we can see above, the `yield` above cannot be assumed ab ovo to be `undefined`. And of course we can pass some custom thenables, like

```
Promise.resolve({ 
  then: function(onFulfill, onReject) { onFulfill('fulfilled!'); }
});
```

or even promises which were not resolved yet. The point of the example was to show that we cannot pass values to the `yield` using the for..of loop, which is quite a feature gap in my opinion.

Comment: The whole point of a `for..of` loop is to automatically call `.next()` on the iterator for you, so there is no way to pass a value in. Perhaps it would be better to focus the question on why you want to do this, so people could offer alternative suggestions?

Comment: @loganfsmyth my aim is to understand the syntax. So far it seems this is impossible with for..of, but I would like to factually know whether that's true.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do with promises. I would recommend to have a look into `async`/`await`.

Comment: @Bergi I have to do a presentation about ES6 on Friday, so my aim is to understand the syntax. I figured out most of the questions I have posed to myself, except this one.

Comment: The `while (promise = yield) Promise.resolve(promise);` statement makes no sense to me. First you assign `undefined` (the value of the `yield` expression) to a variable, which will obviously cancel the loop that's never run in the first place, but only after actually yielding `undefined`, and that's not even talking about what would happen if the loop had run -- creating a promise resolved with `undefined` again, with `Promise.resolve(promise)` and just not doing anything with said promise at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to pass arguments to `next`.

```
function* generateItems() { /* ... */ }
for (var item of generateItems()) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

is *mostly* short for

```
function* generateItems() { /* ... */ }
var iterator = generateItems()[Symbol.iterator]();
do {
  const result = iterator.next();
  if (result.done) break;
  const item = result.value;

  console.log(item);
} while (true);
```

barring a few missing `try/catch` wrappers. You can see [in the spec here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofbodyevaluation-lhs-stmt-iterator-lhskind-labelset) that it calls `.next` with no arguments:

> Let nextResult be ? Call(iteratorRecord.[[NextMethod]], iteratorRecord.[[Iterator]], « »).

e.g.

```
iterator.next.apply(iterator, []);
```

calling `next()` with an empty array of arguments.

Comment: Excellent answer!